# Mistakes with this MATLAB code

Tags: matlab

I have written this script to test the secant method in MATLAB

```
%Test of the Secant Method

function secantm1(x0,x1)

    tol=10^-6; % tolerance
    itmax=1000; % max number of iterations
    itnum=0; % iterations counter


    disp([itnum,x0,x1])
    x2=x1-f1(x1)*((x1-x0)/f1(x1)-f1(x0));
    itnum=itnum+1;
    disp([itnum,x1,abs((x0-x1)/x0)])

    while abs((x1-x2)/x1)>tol && itnum<itmax
        x0=x1; % I think here is mistake
        x1=x2;
        x2=x1-f1(x1)*((x1-x0)/f1(x1)-f1(x0));
        itnum=itnum+1;
        disp([itnum,x1,abs((x1-x2)/x1),x2])
    end

end


function y=f1(x)
y=x^3+x-3;
end
function y=f2(x)
    y=x-tan(x);
end
```

But the thing is that it doesn't run, I have pointed out where I think is the mistake, but I am not quite sure if I am right and how can I fix it.

Can someone help me with this mistake please?

The thing is that when I input f1 I expect to get like 1.23...  but the method doesn't converge, with the other function I expect not convergence

when I run it it gives me the following:

secantm1(1,2)

```
 0     1     2


 1     2     1
```

1.0e+03 *

```
0.0020   -0.0060    0.2612   -1.5730
```

1.0e+11 *

```
0.0000   -0.0000    0.0056    8.7573
```

1.0e+45 *

```
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -2.6139
```

1.0e+172 *

```
0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -1.1995
```

1.0e+172 *

```
0.0000   -1.1995       Inf       Inf

 7   Inf   NaN   NaN
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok , the thing is that when I input f1 I expect to get like 1.23...  but the method doesn't converge, with the other function I expect not convergence

Comment: I have edited my post :)

Comment: Then what can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was you were missing a set of parentheses in the denominator of your iteration update.

i.e

```
x2=x1-f1(x1)*((x1-x0)/f1(x1)-f1(x0));
```

should be

```
 x2=x1-f1(x1)*((x1-x0)/( f1(x1)-f1(x0) ));
```

The corrected secant code should be:

```
    function secantm1(x0,x1)

        tol=10^-6; % tolerance
        itmax=1000; % max number of iterations
        itnum=0; % iterations counter


        disp([itnum,x0,x1])
        x2=x1-f1(x1)*((x1-x0)/ ( f1(x1)-f1(x0) ));
        itnum=itnum+1;
        disp([itnum,x1,abs((x0-x1)/x0)])

        while abs((x1-x2)/x1)>tol && itnum<itmax
            x0=x1; % This was OK
            x1=x2;
            x2=x1-f1(x1)*((x1-x0)/( f1(x1)-f1(x0) ));
            itnum=itnum+1;
            disp([itnum,x1,abs((x1-x2)/x1),x2])
        end
end
```

This will converge to a result now:

secantm1(1,2)

```
 0     1     2

 1     2     1

2.0000    1.1250    0.0471    1.1780

3.0000    1.1780    0.0320    1.2156

4.0000    1.2156    0.0019    1.2134

5.0000    1.2134    0.0000    1.2134

6.0000    1.2134    0.0000    1.2134
```